Linking Python extension module against another extension
I have a setup.py file that looks like this:
from setuptools import Extension, setup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="something",
        license="MIT",
        version="0.1.0",
        ext_modules=[
            Extension(
                "_something",
                ["./file.c"],
                include_dirs=[...],
                extra_objects=["/path/to/my/library/_module.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"]
            )
        ]
    )

I'm trying to link the extension module _something against another installed extension module called _module. I have the path to the shared library file, but when I try to use _something it complains about undefined symbols. I checked that the symbols were actually getting exported via ctypes, so I don't think it's a problem with _module.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?
